# How to select number without ':' from time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, time

I want to select only number without ':' from table of SQL

Comment: So? What did you try?

Comment: Please read this: 
Select Convert (char (5), OnTime, 108)As OnTime
I want to join with this: 
Select replace(OnTime,':','') from AlarmSummary

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Select replace(time_column,':','') from table
```